# Got HP 255 with Ubuntu 12.04 pre installed - how to add dual boot with Mint Debian?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I'm a newbie to Linux. I installed Mint on an old computer and liked it, I would like to dual boot my HP 255 Ubuntu 12.04 laptop with it if possible. As a complete noob when it comes to doing this, I don't want to break the laptop!! How safe is it to just run the Mint installer from the LiveDVD?

Thanks

Stu

Comment: BTW, it's always safe to run any live CD/installer, as long as you just choose to try it out vs actually installing.

Comment: Thanks - I've looked at the distro on the CD and it does look nice on the laptop screen I also had a look at the MATE desktop in Ubuntu but it just isn't as nice as Mint's

Comment: I personally have my own combination of UIs that look good to me and are easy to use.  I don't care for Unity or Gnome shell that much, so I use Gnome fallback with Cairo Dock, and a small auto-hide gnome panel for things that need it.  Very configurable, so it looks and works the way I want.  I use Cardapio menu, which has a wonderful search ability, so I rarely need to actually open it normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough details, nor do I have the patience, to go into details, but having installed many simultaneous versions of various distros to try, and often discard, I can tell you that's it's both easy and dangerous, not necessarily in that order.

The way to do it is to use a live CD or USB distro (so the system on the disk won't be mounted), and make room for a new partition big enough for a new installation.  The size depends on how serious you want it to be, but usually 20 - 30 GB (or less) is plenty. You can also skip this and let the install do the partitioning, but in my experience, it often doesn't do a good job, or is not that easy to understand.  But I'm sure it can be done.

However you do it, you need to be aware of the fact that, by default, the newest installation will modify GRUB, the bootloader, to boot into the new system, and if you were to delete the new system, your old one won't boot without some TLC.  It's not really serious, but you would be forced to learn about how GRUB works a little, which isn't that easy for the faint of heart.

If you are willing and able to learn, you won't break your laptop.  But if not, you will think you have broken it, and for many people, that is the same thing.  Personally, I learn by destroying, so I often just forge ahead and do things that put me in the deep end, but you may not be that type of person.  But once you learn how things work, you will truly control your system, rather than vice versa...  well, more or less. :-)

If you proceed, make sure you can boot from a live CD and get internet access.  At least that way, you can get back here to ask questions if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I thought that this would be the case. I will investigate GRUB a bit more before I attempt to do it.

Comment: I check in regularly, so if you have any questions, I can try to help.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck. If all goes well, you'll find that you no longer need to fear the OS; unlike windows, you can move things around, even move a system to a completely new computer, make a system bootable that got destroyed, etc.

Comment: just running the installer, partitioned the drive to fit the new OS. it's asking me to install grub and options for the whole drive (dev/sda) or the partition only (dev/sda4). Which should it be?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure you should install it on the whole drive.

Comment: GRUB itself goes in the boot partition for the drive.  But part of GRUB is installed in the /boot/grub directory of the partition for the new installation(s), and the bootloader part points to this partition - the latest install.  That makes it confusing, but I'm pretty certain they are asking about the boot loader, and I seem to remember trying it the other way, and failing.

Comment: Thanks for the info - i had already decided to go with on the whole drive - it seems to have worked albeit with a couple of things that don't look quite right like the splash screen for ubuntu has gone very lo res but all programs seem to work ok. so got my first dual boot done!! thanks again for the pointers

Comment: Just remember, the GRUB menu and most code is actually on the partition I mentinoed, so if you delete the newest partition, you won't be able to boot until you point the bootloader code to the old partition again; then, it will be back like it was originally.  Not hard to do, but some people never seem to get it.

Comment: I think I get it - the installer for LMDE seems to be GRUB 1 whereas the original one for Ubuntu was GRUB 2 - this appears to have been replaced by the LMDE one, and that's why the start screen for Ubuntu has gone pixely. I've run update-grub in both distros so hopefully everything is ok... it seems to be so far. Thanks again.

Comment: The current LMDE uses GRUB 2, if that matters.  You actually should be able to use whichever one you want, and for a while, I stuck with GRUB 1 because I understood it better.  But GRUB 2 is worth learning, especially since it's becoming prevalent.  You can replace GRUB 1 with GRUB 2 with no problem.